# CSS Emotion is caching CSS despite variables

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion

I'm using Emotion for CSS in a React project.
It's working correctly but I have one component that uses the `css` property with JS arguments and it seems Emotion is caching the CSS despite the variables changes.

Here's a CodeSandBox to test the behavior : https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-lumiere-bfg7o

When you click on the images, the zoom should start from the top left corner of the image.
It works the first time, but after clicking multiple times on one image then another, Emotion is keeping values in cache (I logged the JS values before sending them to Emotion, you can check in the console)

Animation is slowed down to see the bug.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is this still an issue? I see the same console log every time I click each of the images, even after multiple clicks.